# Convert part of column data to row eg one ID has many appointments with different diagnoses. Change diagnosis row to columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a list of study IDs in an Excel file who some have a single encounters and some with duplicate encounters with different diagnoses as shown in the example below.  I would like if possible to split the file to show the diagnoses as rows but not sure how to do this if it is possible using Power Query or another way using Excel.  Can anyone help please.

[image: example]

Comment: Can you show your expected results and use markdown format for your input table.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the desired output, or give some visual aid?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for": https://stackoverflow.com/q/72200483/4961700

Comment: Hi I would like the output to show each study id's encounter with multiple columns for their diagnosis if possible as shown below:

STUDY_ID ENCNTR_ID Diagnosis 1 Diagnosis 2 Diagnosis 3
AE0032 202311934 Faint Vaso vagal episode Chest pain
AE0091 214109345 Cardiac arrest History of cardiac arrest Bleeding
AE0125 200181582 H/O: stroke  
AE0125 198123251 Referred to plastic surgeon H/O: stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** - Muliple diagnosis merged into one cell

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"STUDY_ID", type text}, {"ENCNTR_ID", Int64.Type}, {"DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"STUDY_ID", "ENCNTR_ID"}, {{"Rows", each _, type table [STUDY_ID=nullable text, ENCNTR_ID=nullable number, DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY", each Text.Combine([Rows][DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY], "#(lf)"), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Rows"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

**Option 2** - Muliple diagnosis into separate columns

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"STUDY_ID", type text}, {"ENCNTR_ID", Int64.Type}, {"DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"STUDY_ID", "ENCNTR_ID"}, {{"Rows", each _ }}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddColumn(Table.AddIndexColumn([Rows], "Index", 1, 1), "Diagnosis", each "DIAGNOSIS " & Number.ToText([Index]))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Rows"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY", "Diagnosis"}, {"DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY", "Diagnosis"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Diagnosis]), "Diagnosis", "DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thank you both options look great but I am not sure know how to do this sorry  Are you able to add a comment at each of the applied steps to allow me to try.

Comment: I tried and did the first one thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"STUDY_ID", "ENCNTR_ID"}, {{"DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY", each Text.Combine([DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY],"#(lf)"), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

One another option using `MS365` functions available in `Beta` Channel:

[image]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(GROUPBY(Table27[[STUDY_ID]:[ENCNTR_ID]],Table27[DIAGNOSIS_DISPLAY],ARRAYTOTEXT,0,0),", ",", "&CHAR(10))
```

---